# Efficiently add data to h5py dataset over a loop

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have `torch.tensors` that I need to save to disk as they are large files and will consume all memory.

I am new to h5py and I am having trouble figuring out how to make a data set efficiently. This process is VERY slow.

Below is a very MWE that I would intend to transform into a loop.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

data = np.random.random((13, 8, 512, 768))

f = h5py.File('C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\test_h5\\xd.h5', 'w')
dset = f.create_dataset('embeds', shape=(13, 8, 512, 768),
                        maxshape=(None, 8, 512, 768), chunks=(13, 8, 512, 768),
                        dtype=np.float16)

# add first chunk of rows
dset[:] = data[0:13, :, :,]

# Resize the dataset to accommodate the next chunk of rows
dset.resize(26, axis=0)

# Write the next chunk
dset[13:] = np.random.random((13, 8, 512, 768))

# check data
with h5py.File('C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Desktop\\test_h5\\xd.h5', 'r') as f:
    print(f['embeds'][0:26].shape)
    print(f['embeds'][0:26])
f.close()
```

## Edit:

I am not having issues figuring out how to ensure the last appended data is actually the last generated data, consider the following:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

data = np.random.random((13, 8, 512, 768)).astype(np.float32)

batch_size=8
with h5py.File('SO_65606675.h5', 'w') as f:
    # create empty data set
    dset = f.create_dataset('embeds', shape=(13, 16, 512, 768),
                            maxshape=(13, None, 512, 768), chunks=(13, 8, 512, 768),
                            dtype=np.float32)
    for cnt in range(2):
        # add chunk of rows
        start = cnt*batch_size
        dset[:, start:start+batch_size, :, :] = data[:, :, :, :]

        # Create attribute with last_index value
        dset.attrs['last_index']=(cnt+1)*batch_size


# check data
with h5py.File('SO_65606675.h5', 'r') as f:
    print(f['embeds'].attrs['last_index'])
    print(f['embeds'].shape)
    x = f['embeds'][:, 8:16, :, :]  # get last entry
np.array_equal(x, data)  # passes
```

Edit2 : I think I had an error above and this works; will check my "real" data.

Comment: You have the right idea. What do you mean by "VERY slow"? I ran your code, and it takes 7 seconds for the first array write, and 7.7 seconds to resize the data set and write the array again. You can save the time spent on resize if you preallocate the data set to the desired size. You can still use `maxshape=` to resize in the future.

Comment: Note: you don't close the file before you open again in the `with / as` structure. That might lead to some misbehavior.

Comment: Thanks, what would I edit to preallocate the data set to the desired size? `shape` or `maxshape`?

Comment: Let's say you want to add data in 10 loops. Use `shape=(130, 8, 512, 768)`. Keep the same `maxshape=` and `chunks=` values (assuming they are correct). If you do this, I suggest adding a "last_index" attribute to the dataset with the last value for axis=0 index (so you know where your data ends and you can start adding data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example that pulls my suggestions together to show how everything might work in your case. Program flow summary:

1. Open a new file, create dataset `'embeds'` with `shape=(130, 8, 512, 768)`, then add 2 sets of data, write the `'last_index'` attribute then close the file.
2. Re-Open the file in APPEND mode, accesses dataset 'embeds', add more 2
   sets of data (starting at 'last_index'), write the `'last_index'` attribute and close the file.
3. The last file open is in READ mode to print dataset attribute and shape
   parameters.

Notes:

- I use HDFView to visually verify dataset contents. I discovered a problem viewing `np.float16`, so I used `np.float32`. This should work with `np.float16`. I will let you verify that.
- You should also add standard integrity checks and error handling. For example: 1) that 'embeds' dataset and the 'last_index' attribute both exist, 2) check the size of the dataset size to confirm data will fit, and 3) resize if your new data goes beyond the current bounds.

**CODE BELOW:**

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

data = np.random.random((13, 8, 512, 768)).astype(np.float32)

with h5py.File('SO_65606675.h5', 'w') as f:
    # create empty data set
    dset = f.create_dataset('embeds', shape=(130, 8, 512, 768),
                            maxshape=(None, 8, 512, 768), chunks=(13, 8, 512, 768),
                            dtype=np.float32)
    for cnt in range(2):
        # add chunk of rows
        start = cnt*13
        dset[start:start+13, :, :, :] = data[:, :, :, :]
        
        # Create attribute with last_index value
        dset.attrs['last_index']=(cnt+1)*13

# add more data
with h5py.File('SO_65606675.h5', 'a') as f: # USE APPEND MODE
    dset = f['embeds']
    for cnt in range(2):
        start = dset.attrs['last_index']
        # add chunk of rows
        dset[start:start+13, :, :, :] = data[:, :, :, :]
    
        # Resize the dataset to accommodate the next chunk of rows
        #dset.resize(26, axis=0)
        
        # Create attribute with last_index value
        dset.attrs['last_index']=start+(cnt+1)*13

# check data
with h5py.File('SO_65606675.h5', 'r') as f:
    print(f['embeds'].attrs['last_index'])
    print(f['embeds'].shape)
    #print(f['embeds'][0:26])
```

Comment: I am wondering if you can further comment as to how to ensure the integrity of the appended data?

I edited my question above with some extra checks and a slight tweak to my structure as I was wrong. Basically, I cannot find that the last appended data matches the last generated data.

Comment: That is a good question. Easier said than done. I suspect your first approach (resizing every time you add data) is the least error prone. There is only a small (10%) performance penalty, so you may prefer to do that. My suggestion uses the 'last_index' attribute to mark the extents of existing data. That _should work_, but you **HAVE TO** remember to update it. It's the only way to be sure. You could check that all values in the target write region are 0.0 (assuming you never write all 0.0 values).

Comment: Regarding your modified question, do you get the correct data if you use resize for axis=1 every time you add data?  If so, I'll have to run some tests to see what's happening. In the end, this is mostly related to NumPy array slicing notation, and not HDF5/h5py specific.

Comment: I think I have it now; I was just making some comparison mistakes. I will look more closely. Your example has been **beyond** helpful.